# Show/hide div(check box) dynamically using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I created a popup box using jQuery. The popup box contains a button named submit.

1.In a table `<td>`, there are two buttons "Add the name" and "Add from list". When the user clicks "Add the name", a popup box will open and get the input from the user (namely text data).

2.After entering the text data in the popup box, they should press the submit button. On clicking submit, the input text entered by the user is displayed in a `<div id="dynamic"></div>` in a `<td>`. (See HTML below).

3.In the HTML below, the second `<tr>`: in a separate I put some text, i.first Aid notes with a check box ii.sent to sick bay with a check box iii.ambulance with a checkbox.

4.When the user clicks the submit button, the text data is displayed in the name `<td>` cell (See HTML below). But what I want is at the same time the above mentioned check box with label should bind in their respective `<td>`s in a table dynamically (See HTML below, I placed it in individual `<td>` (i.e when the user clicks the submit button the check box also should display, this should happen at every click on submit).

I don't know how to perform using Javascript or jQuery. Can any one please come up with code.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="rounded_border">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><p><em>Please record the name</em></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Involved</strong></td>
    <td><a href="#" id="btnShowModal"><button>Add a name</button></a></td>
    <td><p align=center>or</p></td>
    <td>Add from list</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="list"  class="ir-shade"><div id="dynamic">
    <td><span class="delete_icon">x</span>Atil</td>
    <td>
      <input id="firstaid" onclick="addtreatment();" type="checkbox"/>
      FirstAid needed
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="sickbay" onclick="addtreatment();" type="checkbox"/>
      Sent to Sick bay
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="ambulance" onclick="addtreatment();" type="checkbox"/>
      Ambulance
    </td>
  </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8fzD/5/)

This is what i required as ouptup,but it is displayed as in a single `<td>`,i want it to be happen that eack check box and their respective label in individual `<td>.`

How to do with jquery/javascript. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are missing <table></table> tag in the #dynamic div in the fiddle

Comment: I am keeping all three check box in a single div #dynamic.But see above each check box are in separate table <td>,i want it to be print in the same format.So i am searching this,not getting any answer.Please guide me how to do...

Comment: See if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/sdCrd/

Comment: if i enter more than 1 time,the entered data are also displayed inside the popup box.Why sir

Comment: that was because in line 20 we used table as selector. so the cloned row as appended to both the tables. check this http://jsfiddle.net/sdCrd/1/

Answer (score 0):

That would be in your 'addtreatment' function, what code do you currently have there?